# Getting specific element in Json respone without using an external libary

Tags: java

I want to create a GitHub update checker which provides the version of the newest release.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;

    try {
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://api.github.com/repos/MilkBowl/Vault/releases/latest").openConnection();

        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");            
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        try (final InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream(); final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream); final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {

        }
    } catch (final IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (httpURLConnection != null) {
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I got so far. It returns this Json response:

https://api.github.com/repos/MilkBowl/Vault/releases/latest

Now I want to get the "tag_name". How can I do this with plain Java? I do not want to use an external library.

Comment: The Java API for JSON Processing isn't really "external": https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

Answer (score 0):

O well i don't have reputation enough to comment, so...

I think you can use regex to grab only the name, you can use something like this:

```regex
name.+?,
```

And after that apply some replaces for sanitization.
Something like that:

```java
Pattern.compile("'name.+?,'").matcher(your data);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1).replace("\"name\": \"", "").replace("\",", "");
}
```

Comment: Regex on java can be a little confuse, you can go trough that searching for the right regex, or you can do something like this, too: yourreturn.split("tag_name")[1].split("target_commitish")[0].replace("\":","").replace("\",", "").replace(" ", "").replace("\"", "");